# Predicate comparing two keys

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

I am trying to write a predicate to compare two keys in a cloud kit database.  All the documentation I've been able to find only allows you to compare one key against a set value.  Is there a way to write a predicate in swift to compare two keys?

The closest I've been able to come up with is:

```
 let pred = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %K", "keyA", "keyB")!
```

but that keeps crashing on me.

Comment: Why are you wrapping `NSPredicate` in `()`? Take a not that it creates tuple type `(NSPredicate)`.

Comment: @Kirsteins a 1-tuple is indistinguishable from a single value.  `(NSPredicate)` is identical to `NSPredicate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use %@ on R.H.S side insted of %k like this..

%@ is a var arg substitution for an object value—often a string, number, or date.

%K is a var arg substitution for a key path.

```
let pred = (NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "keyA", "keyB")!)
```

Comment: Also, why wouldn't it be %K on the RHS if I am comparing the values of two different keys?  I want to pull back all the records where keyA matches keyB.

Comment: See my answer for more info on %@ vs. %K, but it looks like you need to give us more context to solve your problem, since, the example given executes just fine.  And, fwiw, you want to compare the value associated with two keys, not two keys.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really trying to compare two keys?  Or are you trying to compare the value associated with two keys?  The difference between %@ and %K in a predicate is that %@ will be appropriately escaped, while %K won't be.

So:

```
NSPredicate(format:"value = %@", "Fred")   // yields 'value = "Fred"'
```

While:

```
NSPredicate(format:"value = %K", "Fred")   // yields 'value = Fred'
```

You want to use `%K` when you're passing an key name in as a parameter to the predicate, while you want to use '%@' if you're passing in a value.

From your example, title, and question, it's tough to figure out what you're actually trying to do, if you a predicate that insures that the value of two fields/keys is the same, you want to use

```
NSPredicate(format:"%K = %K", "key1", "key2")
```

as you're doing.

If you're trying to check that a particular key has a particular value, use:

```
NSPredicate(format:"%K = %@", "key1", "value1")
```

The code you've given, in isolation, executes just fine, where and what exactly is crashing, give us a bit more context.

With the further information that you're wanting to filter for records containing the same value in two different fields, it appears that CloudKit doesn't support `field OP field` only `field OP constant`  Given that, the best work around I can suggest is:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(gender1 = \"male\" AND gender2 = \"male\") OR (gender1 = \"female\" AND gender2 = \"female\")")
```

Comment: So specifically, key1 and key2 both have the same type of data.  Either male or female.  I want to find all the results where key1 matches key2.  I'm sorry if my terminology was wrong.  I'm a bit of a noob.

Comment: So each record contains two different gender fields and you want to return the records in which they're the same?

Comment: Then just use `NSPredicate(format:"genderField1 = genderField2")` and avoid the whole issue.  Really, it's pretty rare that you need to use `%K`  The only time you need to use it is if you need to determine the field name dynamically.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'Expected constant value in comparison expression: genderField1 == genderField2'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: try self.genderField1 (and change genderField1 and genderField2 to whatever the actual field names are)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70869/discussion-between-david-and-andy-dewan).

Comment: NSPredicate(format: "%K == %K", "var", "var") doesn't work.  The RHS has to be a variable.  It can't be a key.