# Comparing two key values with NSPredicate CloudKit

Tags: swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

I am trying to write a predicate that compares two keys in a cloud kit database. So far I can compare one of the keys with a constant value. I want to use this to send a notification when the inventory of a product is low.

I have a record type called products which consists of a count that gets updated, and a minCount that never changes. I use this to display an "Inventory Low" label whenever count <= minCount.

Here is an example of the predicate I'm using with the constant value for the notifications:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "count <= %i", 10)
```

For one specific product I know that the minCount is 10, so this works properly for that one product, but the other products have different minCount values. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the CloudKit will expect the right hand side value to be a constant rather than a key, it will throw you the error you are mentioning in the comment to this answer if you to this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "count <= minCount")
```

But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28501535/8160613) this should work

```swift
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K <= %i", "count", "minCount")
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I tried this the first time assuming it would work but I get this error: <CKError 0x2839a82a0: "Invalid Arguments" (12/1009); "Expected constant value in comparison expression: count <= minCount">

Comment: Sadly I've tried this too, here's the error: <CKError 0x2802f8330: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2006); server message = "Field 'count' has a value type of NUMBER_INT64 and cannot be queried using filter value type STRING". I've tried "%@ <= %@" as well and still no luck. heres the error for the latter: "Invalid Arguments" (12/1009); "Expected key-path in comparison expression: "count" <= "minCount"">

Comment: Ive also tried "%i <= %i" and that gives me this error: "Invalid Arguments" (12/1009); "Expected key-path in comparison expression: 1825909938 <= -790364326">

Comment: Are you saying that `count` is a `Int64`, but `minCount` a `String` property in your CoreData object?

Comment: @Larme It’s a CloudKit predicate

Comment: I know, I've been using since ages that kind of predicates in a not a CloudKit, but in "local" CoreData. But reading the error ""Field 'count' has a value type of NUMBER_INT64 and cannot be queried using filter value type STRING"", made me think that maybe `minCount` wasn't an Int, and I use it like this: (`"%K < minCount", "count")`. `%@ <= %@` will always fails, that's normal, same for `%i <= %i`, the left one needs to be a KeyPath, so `%K`.

Comment: Oh I haven’t read though the comment closely enough. You are probably right

Comment: @Larme Both 'count' and 'minCount' are Ints

Comment: "%K < minCount", "count" gives me the following error: "Expected constant value in comparison expression: count <= minCount">